# Publish on facebook wall

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, publish

In my current application I have to publish on a facebook wall (one image + some text + some comments)

I've already done that with the last facebook sdk but with the new I'm completely lost.

(My application is added in the facebook dev platform, the key is generated)

Facebook documentation got me completely lost, it's all too complicated for what I want to do.

Can someone give me a proper clear and simple way (step by step) to do just a **"login? + publish"**

Comment: Please post your code/efforts.

Comment: I don't want to base on what i've done, i just copied the code from a sample of the facebook sdk which doen't help me at all since i don't understand it all. Their is too much. All i want is the simpliest way to publish something, and then go on from that code. This is the basis nad i didn't find it in the documentation :/